# Contest running with Obsidian Portal [Updated May 25th]

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Notice an influx of traffic? Maybe? Sorry to blindside the community with this, but we're running a contest with the website/blog/podcast Obsidian Portal! Details [here](http://blog.obsidianportal.com/rpg-stack-exchange-contest-win-75-worth-of-whatever-gaming-goodness-you-desire/). This has been in the works for a few months, but was never firm enough to warrant a for-reals Meta post until rather soon. In the future, more of a heads up will be given!

Essentially, it's a contest that gets people to check out the site. So far the comments have been really awesome and supportive. If this contest was [Rotten Tomatoes](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/), you guys would be certified fresh!

I'm happy to discuss any of the finer points in comments or chat, just ping me. Sorry to keep this brief, but the reasons I forgot to post a Meta post are the very reasons that I have to be skedaddling right now.

**UPDATE:** The contest ended earlier this week and the winners were [DreamDrake and RobertU](http://blog.obsidianportal.com/rpg-stack-exchange-contest-win-75-worth-of-whatever-gaming-goodness-you-desire/)! We're currently in the process of analyzing the results, but I know both us here at Stack Exchange and the fine folks of Obsidian Portal are happy with the results. We hope to bring more diverse partnerships, events and contests to the community in the future!

Comment: Thanks, @Brett! :D

Comment: Kind of a neat format for a contest. Builds awareness, and encourages people to poke at the site a little bit.

Comment: I'm finding new, interesting questions I'd missed over the past few years in the comment thread :)

Comment: Great format for a contest. Now to figure out how to encourage folks to post questions in addition to answers :).